# No value accessor for form control with name: 'groupName'

Tags: angular6

```
<div class="kit-btn-group" formControlName="groupName">
      <button class="btn btn-add mr-5 mb-5" (click)="selectGroupName()" *ngFor="let groupName of groupDropDown |groupFilter:searchText" [(ngModel)]="groupName">{{groupName.name}}</button>
 </div>
```

Error Message:

> Error: ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
>         formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:

Answer (score 0):

`formControlName` should be placed on the button and not on the div